# Boost: typedef for rpm

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

I'm trying to use boost::units in my code to define a type RoundsPerMinute. However I am not really understanding how to do that.

I've defined a minute via

```
using boost::units::si::seconds;

typedef boost::units::make_scaled_unit < boost::units::si::time, boost::units::scale<60, boost::units::static_rational<1> > >::type minute;
BOOST_UNITS_STATIC_CONSTANT(minutes, minute);

typedef boost::units::quantity<minute, float> Minute;
```

and can now do e.g.

```
Minute m = 5*minutes;
```

What I now would like to do is something along the lines of

```
RoundsPerMinute rpm1 = 50 * rpm;
RoundsPerMinute rpm2 = 100 / (2*minutes);
Minute m = 1/rpm2; // how many minutes does it take for one round?
```

but I am not sure how to define these types - frankly the whole boost documentation is way too technical for me to understand :-( If anybody could help me out with the definitions, this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One RPM is just 1/60 Hertz - see `boost::units::si::hertz`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Hz. I've tried to use it and it seems to work for the basic stuff. However shouldn't I be able to do 1/Hertz to get the time it takes for one iteration? This fails with unknown operator/.

Comment: @Frankie: That doesn't make sense. You do `1/variable` to get another variable. But hertz is a type (as is RPM, both are frequency types).

Comment: Of course I meant 

    boost::units::quantity<frequency, float> freq = 2*hertz;
    boost::units::quantity<second, float> sec = 1/freq;

and I would expect to get sec.value() == 0.5.

Comment: Ah, I seem to have to use 1.0/freq (cmp. answer to 11087802)